# Mongo db aggregation query

Tags: mongodb

here is my collection

```
Tournament 1 {
id:
Name:
Active: No
}
Tournament 2 {
Id:
Name: No
Active: }
...
Tournament 6{
id:
Name:
Active: Yes
PlayerDetails: {type: Array, default: []}
}
```

The above collection will for now have Tournament 6 as Active = "Yes" and then PlayerDetails Array will have the 120 players like so:-

```
[
Player_Name:
Player_Team:
....Another couple of fields.
}
```

The Player_Team field can be one of ten options . I am trying to run an aggregate query to pull only those players that have a certain team name. I am able to $match and $project the array PlayerDetails. But I dont know how to acess the Player_Team field and search for a specific team name. Can some one help please?

Tried query so far:

```
tournamentRegister.aggregate([
        {$match: {Tournament_Active: "Yes"}},
        {$project: {Playerdetails: "$PlayerDetails", _id: 0}},
        //"$unwind": "$Playerdetails",
        {$project:{playerdetails:{$filter:{input:"$Playerdetails", as:"playerdetails", cond:{$eq:{"TeamName": "Busters"}}}}}}
        //$filter: {input:"$Playerdetails", as: "Playerdetails", cond: {$eq: ["$$Playerdetails.$.TeamName", "Busters"]}}}
      ])
```

Comment: Add the query which you have tried.

Comment: The `TeamName` (or is it `Player_Team`) in the `$filter`'s `cond` is to be referred as shown in the [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html#example).